# Нужно изменить значение Switch элемента созданного программно через BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, broadcast-receiver

у меня есть класс **AddAlarmActivity** и в ней функция которая вызывает BroadcastReceiver в отдельном классе **AlarmReceiver** и нужно изменить значение Switch созданный программно, я пробовал это сделать но метод findViewById(); не работает внутри самого класса который наследуется только от BroadcastReceiver, возможно нужно создать его внутри моего класса но у меня не получается.

**AddAlarmActivity:**

```
public class AddAlarmActivity extends Activity {
    public Intent intent;
    public PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    public AlarmManager alarmMgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_alarm);
    }

    public void AlarmOn (Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(AddAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(countID.getText().toString()), intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Switch sw = tableRow2.findViewById(a.USERIDS + id);
        //sw.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: Используйте стандартный BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Можно по подробнее? Что значит стандартный BroadcastReceiver, приведите пример

Comment: Это значит что его не нужно наследовать. Примеры потрудитесь поискать сами.